# Azure websites: domain.tld without www

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I have problem configuring the azure website to run on my domain, but without www.

The background:

- I have the azure website: [zwsfrontend.azurewebsites.net](http://zwsfrontend.azurewebsites.net).
- I have domain firemnidochazka.cz. Here is my CNAME setting - according to these [instructions](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/#bkmk_configurecname):
  [image: CNAME records, sorry for czech, but I hope it is obvious.]
  At the moment I do not have any A records as from above instructions I understood I first must have working CNAME records.

The problem is I think everything is configured properly, but I cannot add firemnidochazka.cz as the domain in Azure management (see picture). But I believe I have set everything as requested.
[image: Azure websites configuration gives me an error]

I can access [www.firemnidochazka.cz](http://www.firemnidochazka.cz), but I cannot access it through [firemnidochazka.cz](http://firemnidochazka.cz). Do I miss something?

PS: CNAME is set for a day so it should not be problem of propagating DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't have a DNS entry for firemnidochazka.cz. You need to add one using your DNS control panel (I guess that's the topic picture). It'll probably need an entry of "." or maybe an "@" symbol.

Comment: Isn't it a "Stejné jako nadřazená složka" which may be translated as "same as superior folder" which is firemnidochazka.cz itself I believe? It points to my website on azure as well.